# Mockery::mock Versus createMock

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm just leaning unit testing with PHP. I'm looking at existing unit tests and I noticed some tests are using

```
$this->createMock(object::class)
```

and other cases are using

`\Mockery::mock(Object::class)`

What are the differences between the two when creating Mocks?

Comment: One is from Mockery, one (probably) from PHPUnit. Same idea, different implementations / features / methods etc.